# Get a value from an observer in a Vuex getter

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex

I have namespace module with a getter method called `allItems()` to get an array of values from a normalized state.

```
...    
getters: {
    allItems(state, getters, { entities }) {
        return state.items.map(function (item){
            return {...entities.product[item]};
        });
    }
}
```

When I try to get other elements, it gives me the "you can't call some property from `undefined` element" error.

If I put `console.log(entities)` I can see the array of elements and when I put `console.log(entities.products)` I got an observer `{__ob__: Observer}` with the data inside but when I put `console.log(entities.products[1])` for example, I got `undefined`. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Vuex constructs Observables from all your state properties, so you will need to think differently here. Try to build a getter with an argument so you can `return getters.productForId(item)`

Comment: @GiacomoVoß sure I have a getter to access individually to a product but If a I want an array of products I can't use `return state.items.map(function (item){
                return getters.getProductById(item);
            });` because gives me an array of undefined

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this creating a method getter called `getEntityById` like this

```
getters: {
    getEntityById: (state) => (entity, id) => {
        return state[entity][id];
    }
}
```

And calling it on a map function